# What to do when a user deletes a famous question?

Tags: discussion

I just happened to come across a [famous-question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/famous-question) that was deleted.

> (post deleted or otherwise unavailable)

link1: https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/28/famous-question?userid=8561

link2: https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/28/famous-question?userid=15988

link3: https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/28/famous-question?userid=667

since a lot of these question help people in general, what to do when one is deleted?

**Note**: when searching [here](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/28/famous-question) you will find more of those

**Edit**: all of the pages whit the afore mentioned message:

https://www.google.nl/#q=post+deleted+or+otherwise+unavailable+site:askubuntu.com

Comment: Famous Question is not always synonymous with "good question"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Users *cannot* delete their own question once it receives an up-voted answer, so it is ***extremely* unlikely** a user will be able to delete their 'famous-questions' after the fact.

Such questions are almost certainly deleted for reasons of moderation.  If you have a question why a particular action was taken, the best place to ask is on this community’s meta forum. Asking in the meta forum allows those who took the action to comment, and will help others to learn about the issues being discussed.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing... they were deleted for a "good" reason...

Comment: Okey. same goes is the asker deleted himself? or when the **user** gets deleted himself

Comment: The question will stay if a user deletes their account. If a user deletes a post we can vote for "undelete" if we felt the post should stay (but a user will not be able to delete their question as soon as we have upvoted answers).